# How can I quickly get $\sin\beta\sec\beta\cot\beta$ from $(1-\sin^2\beta)(1+\tan^2\beta)$?

Tags: trigonometry

> How I can get: 
>   $$\sin\beta\sec\beta\cot\beta$$
>   from:
>   $$(1-\sin^2\beta)(1+\tan^2\beta)$$

Well, my teacher has taught me that I should only allow algebraic changes on only one side of the equation, in this case:

$$(1- \sin^2\beta)(1+\tan^2\beta) = \sin\beta\sec\beta\cot\beta$$

I have to work with the left side of the equation,

**I tried:**

$$(1-\sin^2\beta) = \cos^2\beta$$

$$(1+\tan^2\beta) = \sec^2\beta$$

Therefore,

$$\cos^2\beta\sec^2\beta =?$$

But from here, I have not managed to get anything closer.

So, how can I get to the desired algebraic form? What is the fastest way to get to the demonstration in these cases?

Comment: Recognize that you really just have $1$, and then rewrite $1$ in the desired form. (Kind of a poorly written exercise IMO).

Comment: Therefore, $\cos^2(\beta)/\sec^2 ( \beta) = 1$.

Comment: $\sin(\beta)\sec(\beta)\cot(\beta) = \frac{\sin \beta \cos B}{\cos \beta \sin \beta} = 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that
$$\begin{align}
\cos\beta &= \dfrac{\sin\beta}{\tan\beta} \\
\sec\beta &= \dfrac1{\cos\beta} \\
\cot\beta &= \dfrac1{\tan\beta}
\end{align}$$
Then, your expression can be re-written as
$$\begin{align}
\cos^2\beta\sec^2\beta &= \cos\beta\cos\beta\sec\beta\dfrac1{\cos\beta} \\
&= \require{cancel}\cancel{\cos\beta}\cos\beta\sec\beta\dfrac{1}{\cancel{\cos\beta}} \\
&= \cos\beta\sec\beta \\
&= \dfrac{\sin\beta}{\tan\beta}\sec\beta \\
&= \sin\beta\sec\beta\cot\beta
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

We want to show

$$\sin{\beta}\sec{\beta}\cot{\beta} = (1-\sin^2{\beta})(1+\tan^2{\beta})$$

Recall $\sec^2{\beta}=\frac{1}{\cos^2{\beta}}$, so (from your working):

$$\text{RHS } = cos^2{\beta}\sec^2{\beta}=\frac{\cos^2{\beta}}{\cos^2{\beta}}=1.$$

Now consider the LHS:

$$\sin{\beta}\sec{\beta}\cot{\beta} = \sin{\beta}\frac{1}{\cos{\beta}}\frac{\cos{\beta}}{\sin{\beta}} = 1 = \text{ RHS}$$

and we are done.

Comment: i dont need this, i need to get the RHS from LHS,with algebraic manipulations

Answer (score 1):

For these type of problems,
I write everything in terms of
sine and cosine.
Usually,
the only other identity needed is
$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$.

For the first:

$sin(b)sec(b)Cot(b)
=sin(b)\dfrac1{\cos(b)}\dfrac{\cos(b)}{\sin(b)}
=\dfrac{\sin(b)\cos(b)}{\cos(b)\sin(b)}
=1$.

For the second:

$(1- \sin^2(b))(1+\tan^2(b))
=\cos^2(b)(1+\dfrac{\sin^2(b)}{\cos^2(b)})
=\cos^2(b)\dfrac{\cos^2(b)+\sin^2(b)}{\cos^2(b)}
=\cos^2(b)\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(b)}
=1
$.

Since both are equal to $1$,
they are equal.

Now that we've got this,
let's run one of them in reverse.

$\begin{array}\\
(1- \sin^2(b))(1+\tan^2(b))
&=\cos^2(b)(1+\dfrac{\sin^2(b)}{\cos^2(b)})\\
&=\cos^2(b)\dfrac{\cos^2(b)+\sin^2(b)}{\cos^2(b)}\\
&=\cos^2(b)\dfrac{1}{\cos^2(b)}\\
&=1\\
&=\dfrac{\sin(b)\cos(b)}{\cos(b)\sin(b)}\\
&=\sin(b)\dfrac1{\cos(b)}\dfrac{\cos(b)}{\sin(b)}\\
&=\sin(b)\sec(b)\cot(b)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: i dont need this, i need to get the RHS from LHS,with algebraic manipulations

Comment: Do one of these to get 1, then run the other in reverse.